# Colliding staccato marks and ties

Tags: lilypond

In Lilypond 2.14.2, I've got two staccato eighth notes connected by a tie:

```
d'8 \staccato ~ d' \staccato
```

Unfortunately, the ends of the tie end right at the dots of the staccato, making it look a bit like a smiley face.

Is there a way to offset the tie down a bit to separate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be very well worthwhile to try `d'8-.( d'-.)`, that's to say, use a slur instead of a tie.

Comment: I think there's a good chance that this was what the op intended anyway. To tie two staccato notes seems strange to me.

Comment: I had thought so myself. The staccato marks negate the tie, but staccato under a slur is the usual notation for a *jeté* stroke in violin music.

Comment: Confusing ties and slurs is a very common beginner's mistake with any music notation program., and since Lilypond is focused on notation not playback, you don't get instant feedback that a tie here would play back wrongly.